# Map of Sobject in SOQL query

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

the following Salesforce [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_map_sobject.htm) says that:

**When working with SOQL queries, maps can be populated from the results returned by the SOQL query. The map key should be declared with an ID or String data type, and the map value should be declared as an sObject data type.**

Assume on the Account object I have a field of type text that is **unique** called **uniquetext__c**, how can this be achieved:

```
Map<string, Account> map_acc = new Map<string, Account>([select uniquetext__c, name, customField1, customField 2 from Account limit 10]);
```

My expectation is to have a map between **uniquetext__c** and the **Account sObject**, rather than the **ID** and the  **Account sObject**

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't set what field will be the key when constructing a Map from a SOQL query (AFAIK). But to do it manually all you have to do is...

```java
Map<String, Account> map_acc = new Map<String, Account>();
for(Account a : [SELECT uniquetext__c, name, customField1, customField 2 from Account limit 10]){
    map_acc.put(a.uniqueText__c, a);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I am aware of the for loop shortcut but I was trying to avoid it...

Comment: Yeah I thought so. It would be great to be able to do it without the loop from the map construction maybe it should be added as an improvement suggestion